# How to click on html placeholder link using Splinter? - Says not interactable

Tags: python, html, placeholder, splinter

I am trying to navigate through a data table, but the `Next` button is a placeholder link that my Splinter code cannot click. Therefore, I cannot access the rest of the data I need.

I have tried using:

```
browser.find_by_id('next').first.click()

browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="next"]').first.click()
```

HTML code for the `Next` button (brackets removed):

```
a class="option  clickable " id="next" data-page="1">next
```

Error Message :

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
>    (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: Can you add more contextual logging? Usually it tells you why the element is not interactable. Common reasons are that the element is not rendered, doesn't take up any space or the element is overlaid with another element.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript code directly:

```
browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("next").click()')
```